# Error con bind_param() on bolean

Tags: php, mysql, select

Me sale este error y no entiendo a qué se debe. 
He ejecutado la consulta en el MySQL y no me ha dado ningun error.

[image: Ejecución de la consulta]

```
$stmt=$conectar->prepare('select datos_juego.nombre, datos_juego.fecha_juego, datos_juego.puntuacion, datos_juego.precio, datos_juego.urls, datos_compañia.nombre, datos_compañia.fecha_compañia, datos_compañia.director_general, datos_compañia.director_creativo, datos_compañia.acciones, datos_compañia.ultimo_juego, datos_compañia.urls, criticas_juego.critica_positiva, criticas_juego.critica_negativa from datos_juego, datos_compañia, criticas_juego where datos_juego.id_compañia=datos_compañia.id_compañia and datos_juego.id_juego=criticas_juego.id_juego and datos_juego.nombre like "%?%"'
);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $parametro);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($vnombre, $vfecha, $vpuntuacion, $vprecio, $vurls, $vnombre_compañia, $vfecha_compañia, $vdirector, $vdirector_creativo, $vacciones, $vultimo, $vurls, $vpositiva, $vnegativa);
```

Al ejecutarlo, me aparece este error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\inetpub\DomainGames\funciones\usuario\select-usuario.php:28 Stack trace:
#0 {main}   thrown in C:\inetpub\DomainGames\funciones\usuario\select-usuario.php on line 28
```

Muchas gracias por adelantado. Soy nuevo aquí, no se si esto es información suficiente.

Comment: si hacer var_dump($parametro); antes de $stmt->bind_param('s', $parametro); que te muestra?

Comment: No me sale nada nuevo, solo el mismo error mencionado anteriormente

Comment: estimado el var_dump($parametro); debe imprimirte el valor y el tipo de datos que tiene tu varaible $parametro, lo que puede ayudar a depurar

Comment: agrega despues del var_dump un die.. para detener la ejecución del script. ej:  var_dump($parametro); die();

Comment: Me muestra 

 string(25) "Call of Duty: Black Ops 4"

Comment: Modifica tu sql.. usa like ? en vez de like "%?%"  y en el bind param: $stmt->bind_param('s', "%$parametro%"); (en el bind_param agregas los comodines %)

Comment: Me sigue saliendo el error, ¿con un inner join se arreglará el problema o esa consulta también es correcta?

Comment: cual es la linea 28?? además ojo: en el bind_result repites la variable $vurls

Comment: La línea 28 corresponde a esta $stmt->bind_param('s', "%$parametro%");. También, he cambiado un $vurls por $vurls_com

Comment: se mantiene el mismo error?  dale una mirada a esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394710/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param-on-boolean

Answer (score 0):

Reemplaza tu código por este y prueba:

```
$stmt=$conectar->prepare('select datos_juego.nombre, datos_juego.fecha_juego, datos_juego.puntuacion, datos_juego.precio, datos_juego.urls, datos_compañia.nombre, datos_compañia.fecha_compañia, datos_compañia.director_general, datos_compañia.director_creativo, datos_compañia.acciones, datos_compañia.ultimo_juego, datos_compañia.urls, criticas_juego.critica_positiva, criticas_juego.critica_negativa from datos_juego, datos_compañia, criticas_juego where datos_juego.id_compañia=datos_compañia.id_compañia and datos_juego.id_juego=criticas_juego.id_juego and datos_juego.nombre LIKE CONCAT("%",:s,"%")');
    $stmt->bind_param(':s', $parametro);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($vnombre, $vfecha, $vpuntuacion, $vprecio, $vurls, $vnombre_compañia, $vfecha_compañia, $vdirector, $vdirector_creativo, $vacciones, $vultimo, $vurls, $vpositiva, $vnegativa);
```